# PHP file_get_contents() Chinese character ERROR CODE

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, utf-8

I use `file_get_contents()` to download a JSON. There're some Chinese characters in the URL, I tried to print the URL out, it's OK. But when I ran the program, the URL I put in the function became error code. How do I know that is this URL links to a JSON that links to a MySQL request, and in the console of MySQL, I saw the URL became error code. I tried lots of ways to change URL string to UTF-8 or GB2312, etc, but none of that works. I Wish I could get help here, thanks.

Comment: If you have an error message, PLEASE share it with us. Also we work better from code, so if you show us your code, or a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it will help us to help you

Comment: The question is.. does the JSON contain urls with chinese characters or is the url you access with `file_get_contents` the url with the chinese characters?

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to understand your question. I think i understood the first part of your question:

> I use file_get_contents() to download a JSON. There're some Chinese
>   characters in the URL, I tried to print the URL out, it's OK. But when
>   I ran the program, the URL I put in the function became error code.

You try to access a URL containing chinese characters using `file_get_contents()`:

**The answer to this is:**

You need to encode the part of the url containing chinese characters using `urlencode()` or `rawurlencode()`.

The main difference between `urlencode()`and `rawurlencode()` is, that `urlencode()` converts spaces to `+`. `rawurlencode()` converts spaces to `%20`.

`urlencode` is used for Query Parameters as example `?q=my+search+key`, in every other case you use `rawurlencode`.

**Example:**

```
$test = 'http://www.example.com/'.rawurlencode('以怎么下载').'.html';
print_r($test);
// $html = file_get_contents($test);

// output:
http://www.example.com/%E4%BB%A5%E6%80%8E%E4%B9%88%E4%B8%8B%E8%BD%BD.html
```

I hope it solves your problem.